# executing kompose in openshift throws Unauthorized at the end

Tags: openshift, kompose

Trying to use kompose to deploy a docker-compose file below into OpenShift.
At the last line I just get Unauthorized error which doesnt point where is the root cause.

```
Please note before this I have successfully authenticated using oc login and docker login as below
[centos@master user_interface]$ docker login -u `oc whoami` -p `oc whoami -t` docker-registry.default.svc:5000
Login Succeeded

[centos@master user_interface]$ kompose up -v --provider=openshift -f rak-docker-compose.yml --build build-config --namespace=rak
DEBU Docker Compose version: 3
DEBU Compose file dir: /home/centos/user_interface
INFO Buildconfig using http://abc/prj.git::master as source.
DEBU Compose file dir: /home/centos/user_interface
INFO Buildconfig using http://abc/prj.git::master as source.
INFO We are going to create OpenShift DeploymentConfigs, Services and PersistentVolumeClaims for your Dockerized application.
If you need different kind of resources, use the 'kompose convert' and 'oc create -f' commands instead.

FATA Error while deploying application: Unauthorized
```